Power Automate Flow - 'Condition' to Check if 'Select' Action Output or Table or Excel File Contains a String


I have the above flow:

The 'Follow-up' condition checks if the name of the attachment contains the word 'Follow'
Then the flow moves to create a file from the attachment
Then creates a table from the Excel sheet
Then lists the rows of the table
Then selects only few columns from the table
Then 'Filter Array check' action looks for certain strings using expression:

or(contains(item()?['Group'], 'Service-FRA'), contains(item()?['Group'], 'Service-NLD'))

Then the 'Condition NLD' checks if the body output of the 'Filter array check' is greater than zero before running further actions:


The problem with this method, it is breaking the entire flow, causing the first 'For each' action which comes before 'Get Attachment (V2)' to fail.
If i remove 'Condition NLD' from the flow and add some action directly, the flow works fine.
- Question:
Is there any better way to create a condition that checks if a certain string exists either in the Output of the 'Select' or the output of the table or the file itself?

You are trying to compare an array to a number that is why you are getting an error. Instead, you should be comparing the length of the array like this:

where the expression is:
length(body('Filter_array_check'))


Thank you; that solve the issue.
I was wondering if there is a better way to do the check for the strings; say the condition checks directly if a string exists in the table or the 'Select' output? I would like to put multiple checks for multiple different strings in the same condition.

I updated my answer for you. Also if my answer helped you, you can accept my answer with the checkmark :)

I tried the method you provided in your update, it didn't work. I applied it directly after the 'Select' and removed Filter array check, I got the following error: InvalidTemplate Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition_NLD' at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'contains' expects its first argument 'collection' to be a dictionary (object), an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'.'. and when I applied it after the 'Filter array check', the error mentioned in the initial post occurred.

your first approach is fine. But instead of item, you can just put the body of the select

Tested now, unfortunately the flow fails, the first Apply to each fails as well as the For each before the Get Attachment.

well like I said, your first approach is just fine
